# How can tensorflow feature columns be used for repeatable features?

Tags: tensorflow, logistic-regression

I would like to train a sparse logistic regression to classify users in two classes. One of my features is the users' interests which is non-exclusive (e.g. a user can be interested in cars, books and food) and variable in number: a user may have 5 interests, while another may have only 3, in contrast to the examples shown in the [Deep and Wide tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/wide/index.html) (age, education, etc.). I would like to reuse the code from the deep and wide tutorial as much as possible because eventually I would like to extend my model to have a deep component too. What the easiest way to achieve that? I'm also interested in maintaining the time complexity for training/scoring an example to `O(active_features)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a column for each interest (a boolean value for whether or not it's their interest). That should work if all interests are known. Another way to do it is to use one-hot encoding.

```
E.g. Interests are cars, books and food.
001 is cars
010 is books
100 is food
101 is food and cars
etc.
```

If not all interests are known then you could set the size of the vector to n+1, allocating the additional space for an 'others' category.

Within TensorFlow, you could do something like this if you want to use the SKFlow API.

```
x=tf.SparseTensor([[0,1],[1,0]], [1,1], [2,2])
y=tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(x)
input_layer = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('test', 2) # 2 Being the dimension of the inputs
```

Running this gives the following:

```
sess.run(tf.contrib.layers.input_from_feature_columns(columns_to_tensors={'test':y}, feature_columns=[input_layer]))
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Hi, @craymicheal , could you tell me how I can see the final result of a crossed_column for values read from csv?